# POSTing a request via AXIOS in Vue always returns a 405 and CORS error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, axios, cors

I know this error has multiple solutions and honestly I have tried all of them but it didn't work at all. I am building a Vue App which I am testing in loclahost to send SMS on a button click. Below is the code;

```
            const headers = {
            headers: {
              "content-type": "application/json",
              "Access-control-allow-origin": "*",
              authorization: basicAuthHeader(username, upassword),
              "account-id": Buffer.from(acc_id, "utf8").toString("base64"),
            },
          };

          function basicAuthHeader(uname, upass) {
            let base64String = Buffer.from(
              `${uname}:${upass}`,
              "utf8"
            ).toString("base64");
            return `Basic ${base64String}`;
          }
          axios
            .post(
              `https://www.echomobile.org/api/messaging/send?phone=${phone}&message=${message}`,

              headers
            )
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Another reason why I am stuck is because of the lack of documentation. No matter what I do, I always end up with a CORS and a 405 error. Please help me out.

Comment: You seem to post on an endpoint that doesn't accept `POST` request, you should be able to work with the get method. Have you tried with `GET` method? I don't think if there is an issue with the CORS, it's just the browser that shows this error if a cross-origin request gets failed.

Comment: `Access-control-allow-origin: *` should be on server side